# how can i use mysql case when then if?

Tags: mysql, case

A query that gets status and count data.
Previously, when the condition was 2 or more in the case when then statement, 
the count was unified by 2. (Status values ​​are 0 to 4.)

I would like to modify the values ​​that are 2 or more so that only the number of data of the latest registration date by work ID is obtained.

Is there a way to condition ELSE?

Here is mysql query code :

```html
SELECT A.STATUS, TE.COUNT FROM 
   (SELECT 0 AS STATUS UNION ALL  SELECT 1 UNION ALL  SELECT 2) A
  LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT STATUS  , COUNT(*) AS COUNT
     FROM (
           SELECT CASE WHEN STATUS < 2  THEN STATUS  ELSE 2  END AS STATUS
              FROM tb_exe
              WHERE reg_dt >= curdate()
             ) TE
   GROUP BY STATUS
  ) TE ON A.STATUS = TE.STATUS;
```

table strure :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxAw5.png)

Comment: this is barely understable. Please show table structure, some sample data, and your desired output.

Comment: hi danblck. so, edit my question and put my table structure.

Comment: status is 0 to 4, but for 2, 3, and 4, i want to select the data with the most recent request_dt in group by process_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 
you can use **CASE WHEN** in ladder format. Like **IF , ELSE IF, ....ELSE END**.
For Example,

```
SELECT CASE WHEN STATUS < 2  THEN STATUS 
            WHEN ? THEN  ?
            ...
            ELSE 2  
       END AS STATUS
FROM tb_exe
```

you can not write condition in **ELSE**. but you can ignore else statement. I mean no need to write **ELSE**, if it doesn't required then you can end your statement with **END**.